# Documentation for Azure Notification Hub in Mobile Services server script

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

The documentation for [Azure Mobile Services server script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554226.aspx) does not contain any information for the Notification Hub object you can create by calling:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var hub = azure.createNotificationHubService('<hub name>', '<connection string>');
```

Does the documentation exist for this object?

I am trying to figure out the syntax to send a Template notification with a specific tag (the user id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That object is comes from the [Azure SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node), which is available in GitHub. You can find the documentation specificatlly about notification hubs there as well, in the [section about notification hubs](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node#notification-hubs).

Comment: Thnaks @carlosfigueira. Looks like the documentation only specifies the native send methods, not the template send method. However, I figured it out through trial and error.